# Using a User Control from Another Project

Tags: c#, .net

I have built a user control in a project that I want to re-use in a separate project.  I had seen similar attempts successfully accomplished by adding a reference to the original project and then registering the control via:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AssemblyName" Namespace="AssemblyName.Namespace" TagPrefix="xxx" %>
```

I did something similar, compiling the original project and referencing it in the subsequent one .  The control has an asp:Repeater control within it.  I then registered my control as above and placed the control on my page like so (the control has a string property named prop):

```
<xxx:ControlName ID="ControlId" runat="server" prop="21" />
```

However when I launch the control in the subsequent project, I get a null reference exception and the application chokes. Am I doing this the wrong way?  Is it mandatory that I have an .ascx file in the subsequent project?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks,

pbr

Answer (score 3):

Just as a follow up to this:

I did some further research and learned that the mark-up language (materials on the .ascx page) do not get compiled into the assembly.  Therefore you *must* have the .ascx file within the project that calls it if there is any markup associated with the control.

In the properties dialogue I set up a post-build event that copies the .ascx file over to the subsequent project Controls file.  I reference it as I would any normal User Control and everything works fine.

Hope this helps someone out there with a similar issue,

pbr